# Drupal - Which MySql table contains $footer message

Tags: mysql, drupal, drupal-6

Inherited a mess.  Drupal 6 site with custom theme that has removed all admin access.  That's a different problem though.

Immediately we need to change the footer message text.  Since I don't have admin access, I need to edit via MySql database.

Which Drupal database table contains the $footer message text?

Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Site Footer variable (as configured on the `/admin/settings/site-information` page) is stored in the `variables` table. The `variables` table has two columns: `name` and `value`. The value is obviously stored in the `value` column and it is identified as `site_footer` in the `name` column. So:

```
SELECT value FROM variable WHERE name = 'site_footer'
```

...will give you the current value. Note that the value is [serialized](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php), so make sure you're familiar with how that works if you plan on trying to change it directly in the database.

Answer (score 1):

Footer message can be a lot of different things. I think that you'd better find out where `$footer` or `$footer_message` is output in your theme's `page.tpl.php` and substitute it with the text of your choice. If you could post a copy of `page.tpl.php` (and maybe a link to your site) I could be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about Drupal 6, I believe the footer is the "site_footer" variable in the variables table.

It is possible it could be in node_revision.

If the website uses CCK to add fields to Drupal node types, the CCK data will be stored in content_type_* and content_field_* tables that are dynamically created when you add the CCK fields to the system. These are tied to nodes via their nid and vid values.